# "non-static variable cannot be initialized from a static context" java error

Tags: java

i'm researching on how to make a parameter that accepts any object, i found an answer and i tried recreating the code. but the problem is whenever i initialize Bee,Horse and Apple it always shows the error "non-static variable cannot be initialized from a static context". so how is this wrong?

```
public class Testing{
public static void main(String[]args){
  Bee a= new Bee();
  Horse b= new Horse();
  Apple c= new Apple():
}
private interface holder{
    public int getX();
}
private class Bee implements holder{
    int a=52;
    public int getX(){
        return a;
    }
}
private class Horse implements holder{
    int a=62;
    public int getX(){
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You currently have inner classes, which require an instance of the outter class to instantiate. Make those classes `static`.

Comment: Seeing as you don't have an Apple class, how was this supposed to work in the first place? what exactly is the line the error is shown on?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the class definitions of `Bee` and `Horse` from:

```
private class Bee implements Holder {...}
```

to:

```
private static class Bee implements Holder {...}
```

without the `static` keyword the class is treated as an inner class and needs an instance of the enclosing class to be instantiated. E.g without `static` you'd have to write:

```
Testing testing = new Testing();
Bee bee = testing.new Bee();
```

Which doesn't make sense, because `Testing` and `Bee` aren't really related. So with the `static` it can be done like you tried:

```
Bee bee = new Bee(); // works
```